# More pythonic way for dealing with lists and dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.4

I'm looking for a more pythonic 2.4 way of doing the following:

```
for (keys, values) in my_dict.iteritems():
    fmt_str = '%s, %s' % (keys[0], keys[1])
    for value in values:
        fmt_str = '%s, %s, %s' % (fmt_str, value[0], value[1])
    print fmt_str
```

Note: my_dict is composed of tuples for the key and from list of tuple for value.

Comment: What do you find un-Pythonic about your current code?

Comment: You should give us a sample input and the desired output...

Comment: Is anything in `keys` or `values` ever not a string already?

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
from itertools import chain

for keys, values in my_dict.iteritems():
    fmt_str = ', '.join(map(str, chain(keys, *values)))
    print fmt_str
```

If all values in `keys` and `values` are strings already, then you can remove the `map(str, ...)` call:

```
for keys, values in my_dict.iteritems():
    fmt_str = ', '.join(chain(keys, *values))
    print fmt_str
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
for (keys, values) in my_dict.iteritems():
    pairs = [keys] + list(values)
    print ', '.join(['%s, %s' % (pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in pairs])
```

if I'm really bound to Python 2.4 (AFAIR there were list comprehensions at that time, but no generator expressions).

In later versions, I would indeed use a generator expression and do

```
print ', '.join('%s, %s' % (pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in pairs)
```

or even

```
print ', '.join('%s, %s' % (pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in itertools.chain([keys], values))
```